# 2000s fantasy book, teen boy followed home by crows/ravens, feels a weird presence when entering his house and is rescued by a stranger

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

The book takes place in winter and starts off by following a young boy who just turned a certain age like 13 or in that range.  The boy notices that as he was walking back home that crows or ravens were following him and looking at him with intelligence.  As he passes each crow, it looks directly at him at caws while looking at him. The boy remarks on the strangeness but shrugs it off at first.

When the boy gets home, it is dark and there are street lights and as he is about to enter his home he feels a strange presence and turns around and some of the street lights are out and he feels someone watching him.

I don't remember much more than that in specifics. I want to say that something happens that night and the boy is rescued by a stranger who is fighting a battle with the people that were following the boy. I believe there is magic in there as well something that has to do with the seasons or night and day but i am not sure.

Comment: Do you remember anything about the boy (name, why he was being followed)? Do you remember when you read it and who it was aimed at? Can you remember any specific dialogue or words that were unique/unusual?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen an *immediately* self-answered [tag:story-identification] question before.

Answer (score 6):

The book series is called [*The Dark is Rising*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Is_Rising_Sequence) (1965-1977) by Susan Cooper.

Will Stanton, the seventh son of a seventh son, is actually one of the Light and an Old One, and is now coming into his powers. He soon meets up with a mentor, Merriman Lyon, and they have to acquire certain magical artifacts that will be used to fight against the Dark.

In the beginning of the first book, it is the main character's birthday, and the rooks outside are acting strangely,

Comment: Can you confirm why you think this is the right book?

Comment: That exact scene is in the book. Will (ha-ha) add more details to the answer.

Comment: @mkennedy - What you've added doesn't suggest that this is the right book

Comment: I have the Dark is Rising books, but I have to say I can't find any scene like the one described in the question.

Comment: Upon reading the question, "The Dark is Rising" immediately sprang to mind, before seeing this answer... Rooks are "close enough" to ravens and crows. Themes of light and dark, seasonal (or, at least a strong emphasis on the Yule)...

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer (click the checkmark on the left) so that the question is marked as solved.